# поиск всех вхождений preg_match_all

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

День добрый.
Имеется хтмл код вида

```
...
{if var > 0}
тут хтмл код
{else}тут другой хтмл код
{endif}
.....
{if id < 6}тут хтмл код{else}тут другой код{endif}
...
```

Пытаюсь найти все вхождения подходящие под шаблон:

```
!{if ([a-z0-9:]{3,20}) ([\=\=|>|<|\!\=]{1,2}) ([0-9a-z]{1,20})}(.*?){else}(.*?){endif}!U
```

Использую **(.*?)** так как внутри условий может быть любое содержимое (не только хтмл код и текст).

Проблема в том что если условие одно, находит всё корректно. Но если условий больше, берётся весь кусок кода от первого **{if** до последнего **endif}**.

Comment: Такие задачи решаются не регулярками, а через построени AST. Парсить рекурентные структуры регулярками -- дохлый номер (хотя это, теоретически, возможно).

Comment: А каким способом построить такое дерево?

Comment: Приведите пример текста на котором находит нежелаемый результат.

Answer (score 1):

Флаг **U**, который Вы применили к регулярному выражению делает квантификации `*?` жадными, а квантификации `*` - минимальными.
Достаточно просто убрать его и все у Вас заработает:
https://regex101.com/r/kB7nS3/1
Почему всего одно совпадение, а не 2 ? Вы сами указали, что символа должно быть минимум 3:

```
[a-z0-9:]{3,20}
```

Убрать флаг- и будет работать. Кривенько конечно работать будет, поэтому немного исправил Ваше регулярное выражение.

```
{if +([a-z0-9:]{1,20})+ +(==|>|<|\!=) +([0-9a-z]{1,20})}(.*?){else}(.*?){endif}
```

https://regex101.com/r/kB7nS3/2

Comment: к сожалению php ничего незнает о флаге g.

Comment: Конечно не знает. Это фишка regex101. В PHP есть  `preg_match_all` вместо этого флага.